# How can i use/define a constant variable in jmeter for different input jsons

Tags: rest, api, jmeter

I need to use a constant (say phone number) for different json's input while testing rest API's how can I define or declare them

Answer (score 0):

Use [User Defined Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#User_Defined_Variables) for this purpose.

Add the variable and give it a constant value (i.e phone number) so that you can use it in your test plan for different JSON input.

Example:

Adding Variable:

[image]

Using the variable:

[image]